# How do you access to your image resources in MVVM WPF applications?

Tags: wpf, image, resources

I have been integrating image resources to my WPF assemblies for quite a time, but I never really found a really pretty way of binding them in my MVVM applications.

So I was wondering if some you, stackoverflow users, could share their own practice when it comes to assembly ressources:

- How do you reference them in C#/VB and XAML?
- When exposing them from code, what type do you expose? (BitmapImage, Uri, string, ...)
- Do you prefer referencing them from the view or binding them through view-model?
- Do you use a specific assembly to store them? How do you organize them?

Thanks for your help ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I do...

1. Images are kept in some folder such as `Images` in project's root folder. You can keep them in any assembly.
2. Individual image has `Build Action` property set to `Resource` type.
3. The ViewModel holds image name in `string` (say property `MyImageName`) and I convert it as a **relative** path when bound to the `Source` of `Image` object in XAML...

   ```
   public class ImagePathConverter
   {
      public void Convert(...)
      {
         return "pack://application:,,,/MyApplicationName;component/Images/" + value.ToString();
      }
   }
   ```

where `MyApplicationName` is the short assembly's name that is having the `Images` folder under it.

1. In XAML, assuming the view model instance is bound to the data context of the entire view and / or atleast to the image's data contect ....

   ```
   <Image Source="{Binding Path=MyImageName, Converter={StaticResource ImagePathConverter}}" />
   ```

But then thats one of the typical ways to refer images in a WPF project via MVVM. Other ways include an Image's binary stream loaded (from `resx` or `Content` type images or  from binary database). In such case your converter will convert it into a `BitMapImageSource`.

Comment: Not the best practice :). I would rather create some enum on viewmodel representing each image type and wrote converter for converting type to image. Much more code, but much better maintability and testability.