# Binding Image Source to resource file based on some other property

Tags: wpf, binding, resources, ivalueconverter

I have a `ListView` whose `ItemsSource` is bound to a collection.
One of the columns of the `ListView` is an image. This image source must be set to a resource file, and the resource is determined by a property of the item.

How Can the converter return the Image source as resource file?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewTemplateColumn Header="" Width="20" IsReadOnly ="True">
                    <GridViewTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Male}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewTemplateColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Resources.Name,
                                Source={StaticResource resourceHelper}}"
                                Width="SizeToCells"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Fullname}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Resources.Address,
                                Source={StaticResource resourceHelper}}"
                                Width="SizeToCells"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Address}" />

            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

So in above case, if it is Male then show icon1 else show icon2.

Comment: Not related to your question: You are having a gridview inside a list view. I don't think that this is good practice. Why you not only use GridView?

Comment: Thanks, But That is not what my question is about.

Comment: Try out this solution,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402386/how-do-you-access-to-your-image-resources-in-mvvm-wpf-applications